# Post can't be updated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, rake

I tried to update a post and it tells me "Target language was successfully updated" but actually as soon as I hit the update button, the post goes back to original. I can't find any error messages in the log, anybody could help me?

The result when I run rake routes

```
   project_target_langs GET    /projects/:project_id/target_langs(.:format)          target_langs#index
                         POST   /projects/:project_id/target_langs(.:format)          target_langs#create
 new_project_target_lang GET    /projects/:project_id/target_langs/new(.:format)      target_langs#new
edit_project_target_lang GET    /projects/:project_id/target_langs/:id/edit(.:format) target_langs#edit
     project_target_lang GET    /projects/:project_id/target_langs/:id(.:format)      target_langs#show
                         PUT    /projects/:project_id/target_langs/:id(.:format)      target_langs#update
                         DELETE /projects/:project_id/target_langs/:id(.:format)      target_langs#destroy
                         POST   /projects/:project_id/target_langs/:id(.:format)      target_langs#update
```

My controller code

```
def update

    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    @targetLang = @project.targetLangs.find(params[:id])


    respond_to do |format|
      if @targetLang.update_attributes(params[:targetLang])
        format.html { redirect_to project_path(@project), notice: 'Target language was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Show.erb

```
<% @project.targetLangs.each do |targetLang| %>

    <%= form_for([targetLang.project, targetLang]) do |f| %>

            <%= f.text_field :language, :class => 'textbox1' %> 
            <%= f.text_field :status, :class => 'textbox1' %>
            <%= f.text_area :notes, :size => "30x2", :class => 'textbox1' %>
            <%= link_to 'Remove', [targetLang.project, targetLang],
                    :data => {:confirm => 'Confirm deletion!'},
                    :method => :delete %>
            <%= link_to 'Update', [targetLang.project, targetLang],
                    :method => :update %>
```

routes.rb

```
Dashboard::Application.routes.draw do
    resources :projects do
    resources :target_langs
    match '/target_langs/:id' => 'target_langs#update', :via => :post   

 end
```

My log

```
Started POST "/projects/5/target_langs/14" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-07-31 10:14:58 -0400
Processing by TargetLangsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"kTkBzwah/MylU9N96i+s5lu99PskX28XF0eK1THsHLY=", "project_id"=>"5", "id"=>"14"}
  ←[1m←[35mProject Load (0.0ms)←[0m  SELECT "projects".* FROM "projects" WHERE "projects"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "5"]]
  ←[1m←[36mTargetLang Load (0.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT "target_langs".* FROM "target_langs" WHERE "target_langs"."project_id" = 5 AND "target_langs"."id"
= ? LIMIT 1←[0m  [["id", "14"]]
  ←[1m←[35m (0.0ms)←[0m  begin transaction
  ←[1m←[36m (0.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mcommit transaction←[0m
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/projects/5
Completed 302 Found in 125ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
Started GET "/projects/5" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-07-31 10:14:59 -0400
Processing by ProjectsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"5"}
  ←[1m←[35mProject Load (0.0ms)←[0m  SELECT "projects".* FROM "projects" WHERE "projects"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "5"]]
  ←[1m←[36mTargetLang Load (0.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT "target_langs".* FROM "target_langs" WHERE "target_langs"."project_id" = 5←[0m
  ←[1m←[35mProject Load (0.0ms)←[0m  SELECT "projects".* FROM "projects" WHERE "projects"."id" = 5 LIMIT 1
  ←[1m←[36mCACHE (0.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT "projects".* FROM "projects" WHERE "projects"."id" = 5 LIMIT 1←[0m
  ←[1m←[35mCACHE (0.0ms)←[0m  SELECT "projects".* FROM "projects" WHERE "projects"."id" = 5 LIMIT 1
  ←[1m←[36mCACHE (0.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT "projects".* FROM "projects" WHERE "projects"."id" = 5 LIMIT 1←[0m
  ←[1m←[35mCACHE (0.0ms)←[0m  SELECT "projects".* FROM "projects" WHERE "projects"."id" = 5 LIMIT 1
  Rendered projects/show.html.erb within layouts/application (46.9ms)
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 94ms (Views: 93.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/assets/custom.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-07-31 10:14:59 -0400
Served asset /custom.css - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
[2012-07-31 10:14:59] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true


Started GET "/assets/projects.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-07-31 10:14:59 -0400
Served asset /projects.css - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
[2012-07-31 10:14:59] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true


Started GET "/assets/application.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-07-31 10:14:59 -0400
Served asset /application.css - 304 Not Modified (31ms)
[2012-07-31 10:14:59] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true


Started GET "/assets/scaffolds.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-07-31 10:14:59 -0400
Served asset /scaffolds.css - 304 Not Modified (15ms)
[2012-07-31 10:14:59] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true


Started GET "/assets/target_langs.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-07-31 10:14:59 -0400
Served asset /target_langs.css - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
[2012-07-31 10:14:59] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true


Started GET "/assets/jquery.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-07-31 10:14:59 -0400
Served asset /jquery.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
[2012-07-31 10:14:59] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true


Started GET "/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-07-31 10:14:59 -0400
Served asset /jquery_ujs.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
[2012-07-31 10:14:59] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true


Started GET "/assets/projects.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-07-31 10:14:59 -0400
Served asset /projects.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
[2012-07-31 10:14:59] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true


Started GET "/assets/target_langs.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-07-31 10:14:59 -0400
Served asset /target_langs.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
[2012-07-31 10:14:59] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true


Started GET "/assets/application.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-07-31 10:14:59 -0400
Served asset /application.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
[2012-07-31 10:14:59] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true


Started GET "/assets/telelingua.gif" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-07-31 10:14:59 -0400
Served asset /telelingua.gif - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
[2012-07-31 10:14:59] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true
```

Comment: Please add the log part of the #update action so we can check if it actually updates in the DB

Comment: @AnthonyAlberto oops, I do have another part of the code and I uploaded it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there's a simple problem here.

You have two links, one to :delete (which I guess works) and the other to :update (which doesnt work)

Simply put, in HTML an `<a>` tag (which is what `link_to` returns) will not submit a form.

When you click "Update" in your example, the only parameter you are sending is the id.

Instead you should say `submit_tag("Update")`

This will submit the form, and all should be well.

Comment: You mean change <%= link_to 'Update', [targetLang.project, targetLang],
                    :method => :update %> into <%= submit_tag("Update")%> ? I tried, it still doesn't work.

Comment: well the `link_to` is never going to work. In which case there must be another problem too.

Comment: I updated my log and could you check if it updates in the DB?

Comment: As Matthew told you, you have to use a submit_tag. Then in your controller your should be getting `params[:target_lang]` and not `params[:targetLang]`. Post the updated log with a proper submit if you're still stuck